# Variable string limit "%*s" with sscanf() ==> "data argument not used by format string"

Tags: c, scanf, warnings, strlen, format-string

```
int y = strlen(target);
sscanf(p,"%*s",y,buffer);
```

Why does the above code result in `warning: data argument not used by format string` ??

Compiled with `Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)`.

**Aim :** To get the same number of characters as in a string `target` into the string `buffer`, where `p` is a `char *` pointing to some element of a string.

Comment: `*` in a `sscanf` format specifier is different than `*` in a `printf` format specifier. Be sure to consult the documentation for `sscanf`.

Comment: @user3386109 how would I implement this correctly ?

Comment: You don't. `sscanf` does not provide a variable string limit.

Comment: You use `sprintf` to build a format string for `sscanf` :)

Comment: Wow, is there no way to get a variable number of characters from a string in C ?

Comment: @ikegami what ?

Comment: You may want to [edit] the question to explain what it is that you're trying to accomplish. `sscanf` is probably not the right tool for the job.

Comment: Edit the question by specifying what you are trying to do.

Comment: I meant `sprintf`. Fixed

Comment: Re "*Wow, is there no way to get a variable number of characters from a string in C*", `%s` and `%5s` both read a variable number of characters. (Unbound in the first case, and up to five in the latter.)

Comment: @ikegami no, `%5s` wouldn't be variable, from what I mean, it would be a number known at compile-time.

Comment: Copying anywhere from 1 to 5 character as `%5s` is indeed copying a variable number of characters. You actually want the opposite. You want to copy of specific number of characters. You can use `memcpy` for that.

Comment: `sprintf(buffer, "%.*s", y, p)` should do the trick.

Comment: Try `sprintf(buffer, "%*s", (int) strlen(target), p);`

Comment: @M. Nejat Aydin , My apologies. I thought you used `sscanf`. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want

```c
#include <string.h>

memcpy(buffer, p, strlen(target));
```

Note that this will not add a terminating NUL. This can be achieved as follows:

```c
#include <string.h>

size_t len = strlen(target);
memcpy(buffer, p, len);
buffer[len] = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

Other answers explain that `sscanf` does not provide for taking field widths from arguments.  But with respect to this:

> **Aim** : To get the same number of characters as in a string target into the string buffer, where p is a char * pointing to some element
> of a string.

I/O functions such as `sscanf()` are comparatively heavyweight.  If all you want to do is copy (part of) one string to another, then `memcpy()` or `strncpy()` would be more suited to the task.  Or `strncat()`, whose properties make it superior to the other two for this particular task, as with it you do not have the risk of overrunning your source string that `memcpy()` would bring, or the need to manually ensure termination of the result that comes with both `memcpy()` and `strncpy()`.  Example:

```
*buffer = '\0';         // start with an empty string
strncat(buffer, p, y);  // concatenate the wanted region of the source string
```

Answer (score 3):

With `sscanf()`, the `*` in `"%*s"` is an argument suppression, not a size.

`sscanf(p,"%*s",y,buffer);` simply scans `p` for a non-white-space string without saving anything.  `y, buffer` are unused.

---

Recommend to research `fgets()`.